# Application crash when using 3G

Tags: windows-phone-7

I developed an application wchich is using sockets to connect with several servers. The  application works fine with WI-Fi connection but crashes on 3g connection (of course on real device, on emulator everything works fine). I cannot debug it due to the fact that it works wken phone is connected to PC. How to handle this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to both [`Application.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.unhandledexception%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) (for UI thread exceptions) and [`AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (for all unhandled exceptions) and try to write to a file before your process is terminated.

After the application crashes, use the [ISETool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) command line to copy the data back to your machine.

```
Application.Current.UnhandledException += (s,e) => 
    WriteExceptionFast(e.ExceptionObject, "ApplicationUnhandled");

AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException += (s,e) => 
    WriteExceptionFast(e.ExceptionObject, "AppDomainUnhandled");

private void WriteExceptionFast(Exception ex, String name)
{
    string filename = Path.ChangeExtension(name, ".log");

    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    using (var stream = store.CreateFile(filename))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First: catch the exceptions and read them.

Secondy: I expect that you are running into not being able to connect to sockets due to firewalls protecting intranet machines from being accessed from outside.